# Own distro, own name?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, backtrack

There are lots of tools to modify the system of Linux distro.
I would like to start own OS. But I am not good at such programming.

If I take Linux Fedora... I would use this tools and install important packages.
Could I call this a new distro, like "Linux XYZ"?

I've seen that about Linux Backtrack, which is just remade Ubuntu.
May I also remake ready Linux distro to my own?

Shortly, may I modify Linux distro and give it my own name?

Comment: You may but if you suck at programming is it not a good idea, since you'll have to write some automation.  There are tens of thousands of packages in ubuntu, you can't do all this manually.  This is a mammoth task.  Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Not such bad though. I know function apt-get, and using terminal for Ruby and Perl things.

Comment: @goldilocks. Answer given... /close_request

Comment: Probably, if you really want to, but you'll have to read the licenses for ALL of the packages you included to determine what's legal.  Of course, open source software can mostly be copied freely, but there are some nuances, especially regarding names and attribution.

Comment: Offcourse I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I still don't get why you want to make a new distribution. Especial Fedora and Debian have plethora of forks. What are you actually looking for in your own distribution? Different basic set of packages?

Comment: @peterph Personal reasons...

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can take e.g. Fedora and create your own [spin](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Spins?rd=Spin) of it, and say it's Verafter's Fedora as long as you abide by the rules laid down by the distribution. I'm sure digging around in the webpages for your favorite distribution will get you the rules for them.

Generally speaking you usually can, since the licenses are very open, but you may need to change the branding (as authors of the parent distribution likely will not want to be directly connected with your distribution).

But probably you'll want to start by getting whatever packages interest you most into your distribution.

Comment: @Mat, look at the page I link to. The rules to call it that are laid out there.

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed that was a link and that it was an actual "technical" term - I'd not really call that a distro though, it's just a customized Fedora.